# Unable to uninstall KB5006670 even in Safe Mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, uninstall

The KB5006670 update makes our computers unable to use/connect to the network printers. I uninstalled it just fine on 2 other desktop computers. However there's 1 Dell laptop running Windows Home that gave me the "security update is required and cannot be uninstalled" error message when I tried to use wusa on cmd in Safe Mode.

Removing printers and re-adding doesn't work.

Uninstalling with Control Panel doesn't work (no Uninstall option)

wusa with cmd (run as admin) doesn't work on both normal boot and safe mode.

Please help.

Comment: That is an older print problem in general. Make sure Windows is completely up to date including driver updates. Then follow the points in this Microsoft Article.  .... https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-kb5006670-update-print-problem/6a1e36ae-9080-420b-bac9-60bb8314eaf1

Comment: Try "Windows Update Rerset" https://wureset.com/downloads.html (Launch as Administrator) after restart try wusa again.